# Using browser-sync to Reload Page on CSS changes

Tags: html, css, gulp, browser-sync

I'm using [Basscss](http://www.basscss.com/) on a project and trying work out how to set up a task in Gulp that will refresh my browser when I make changes to my `.scss` file.

The current `gulpfile.js` [looks like this](https://github.com/jxnblk/basscss/blob/master/gulpfile.js) and I was thinking of using [Browser Sync](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=browser%20sync) to do this. Except I'm not sure how to implement this since this framework uses Swig templates.

I was thinking of doing something like this, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('watch-css', ['basswork', 'site-basswork', 'customizer-data'], function() {
  gulp.watch([
    './src/**/*.css',
    './docs/src/css/**/*.css'],
    ['basswork', 'site-basswork', 'customizer-data', 'bs-reload']);
});
```

If anyone could lend any help to me regarding this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ending up solving it like so:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./"
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src(['./scss/*.scss'])
  .pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'expanded'
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
  .pipe(minifycss())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Now every time I make a change to my .scss files, the browser is refreshed with the updated CSS. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you starting the server? Did you try to follow [official docs](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/)?

You have to set up task similar to this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});
```

You don't need a task to reload browser-sync, every time you call this task, it will either create server if it's not running, or sync/reload files.

And on watch, you can just add `browser-sync` task to the array of called tasks, similar to what you're doing now:

```
gulp.task('watch-css', ['basswork', 'site-basswork', 'customizer-data'], function () {
    gulp.watch([
        './src/**/*.css',
        './docs/src/css/**/*.css'
    ], ['basswork', 'site-basswork', 'customizer-data', 'browser-sync']);
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this because it looks like a server is being started on line 31. Wouldn't these servers conflict?

Comment: Line 31? What do you mean?

Comment: I linked the current gulpfile in the question (https://github.com/jxnblk/basscss/blob/master/gulpfile.js). Line 31 has a task called `serve`.

Comment: Why are you creating gulp-webserver? Browser-sync will make a server for you.

Comment: I'm not, the gulp-webserver comes with it so I figured I'd use it. I've also never used swig before so I wouldn't know how to serve a website with browser-sync using swig templating.

Comment: [tasks/serve.js:6](https://github.com/jxnblk/basscss/blob/master/tasks/serve.js#L6) is creating a server from `./` (current folder), relative to gulpfile.js. AFAIK you have to precompile any templates, you can use [`gulp-swig`](https://github.com/colynb/gulp-swig) to automate this. After you have compiled files, any static server (gulp- webserver, connect, livereload, browser-sync, etc.) will work the same, you provide server root, and it translates the path from browser to server root and returns corresponding file.

Comment: Okay, I've got it partly working. But every time I make a change to the CSS it opens two browser windows instead of just reloading the current window... Any ideas?

Comment: No idea, I did as I've said with every project and it works. Try adding [browser reloading](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-reload) instead of whole browsersync task.